# C# BinaryWriter, Write with 8 bit

Tags: c#, oracle, blob, filestream

Im Using Binarywriter to save blob data (PDF) from oracle to disk.
The result is ugly when i open the generated file. I think its the problem of that 1 character is write with one byte.

How can i increase to write to 8. (/BitsPerComponent 8)

Any Ideas ?

```
long CurrentIndex = 0;
int BufferSize = 10000;
long BytesReturned;
byte[] Blob = new byte[BufferSize];

OracleDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
string filepath = "C:\\ttttt.pdf";
while (reader.Read())
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs);
    //reset the index to the beginning of the file
    CurrentIndex = 0;
    BytesReturned = reader.GetBytes(0, CurrentIndex, Blob, 0, BufferSize);
    while (BytesReturned == BufferSize)
    {
        writer.Write(Blob);
        writer.Flush();
        CurrentIndex += BufferSize;
        BytesReturned = reader.GetBytes(0, CurrentIndex, Blob, 0, BufferSize);
    }

    writer.Write(Blob, 0, (int)BytesReturned);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple rows returned by the query, you will be overwriting each PDF file returned, the final file may have garbage at the end if any preceding PDF was longer than the last. You should use FileMode.Create rather then FileMode.OpenOrCreate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a BinaryWriter for this. Just write to the stream directly. BinaryWriter's intended use case is writing primitive data types to a stream for serialization purposes.

**Update:** Automatically generate a filename from `Base64(MD5(Blob))`.

```
long CurrentIndex = 0;
int BufferSize = 10000;
long BytesReturned;
byte[] Blob = new byte[BufferSize];

using (var hasher = MD5.Create())
{
    using (var reader = comando.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var filename = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(Blob)).Replace("=", string.Empty);
            var filepath = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine("C:\\", filename), ".pdf");
                
            using (var fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                //reset the index to the beginning of the file
                CurrentIndex = 0;
                BytesReturned = reader.GetBytes(0, CurrentIndex, Blob, 0, BufferSize);
                while (BytesReturned == BufferSize)
                {
                    fs.Write(Blob, 0, Blob.Length);
                    CurrentIndex += BufferSize;
                    BytesReturned = reader.GetBytes(0, CurrentIndex, Blob, 0, BufferSize);
                }

                fs.Write(Blob, 0, (int)BytesReturned);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Weichold, it returns the follow error "There is not argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'offset' of 'FileStram.Write(byte[], int, int) at the instruction "fs.Write(Blob)", Any ideas ?

Comment: At which line does the compiler complain?

Comment: If the query returns multiple rows, won't this append each of them in a single file - which is not valid for a PDF file. Even if there is only 1 row returned, if the file already exists & is longer than the result - it will end up with garbage at the end if FileMode.OpenOrCreate is used.

Comment: @PaulF Didn't occur to me that he wants one file per blob but makes sense.

Comment: @user2232273 Do you need one file per blob?

Comment: @Oliver Weichhold, yes, one file per blob

Comment: @OliverWeichhold, i have updated the code, but the error are still the same

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />

Comment: Updated the code again.

Comment: Yes, it works, but the result are the same when i use the binarywriter.

Comment: Then either the data in the database is already corrupt or the OracleDataReader is messing with it. I suspect the former.